# אלהים vs האלהים - what's the difference?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, theology, shemos-sacred-names

Those (Elohim and Ha'Elohim) two are used in different places and both translated as "יי" - G-d. For example ([Shmos 18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.18.12?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Onkelos_Exodus.18.12&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he)):

> "...אֵת כָּל־אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה **אֱלֹהִים** לְמֹשֶׁה וּלְיִשְׂרָאֵל" - כָּל דִי עֲבַד יְיָ לְמשֶׁה וּלְיִשְׂרָאֵל עַמֵהּ"
>
> "...לֶאֱכָל־לֶחֶם עִם־חֹתֵן מֹשֶׁה לִפְנֵי **הָאֱלֹהִים**" - "לְמֵיכַל לַחְמָא עִם חֲמוּהִי דְמשֶׁה קֳדָם יְיָ"

What's the difference and when ה the definite article is used in reference to G-d?

Comment: @rosends It may be worthwhile to merge your points on the topic into this thread, rather than deleting it entirely. With Al's permission, of course.